# When does exception handling unexpectedly influence object lifetimes?

Tags: python, exception, object-lifetime

The Python [reference on the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) notes that

> catching an exception with a ‘try…except’ statement may keep objects alive.

It seems rather obvious that exceptions change control flow, potentially leading to different objects remaining referenced. Why is it explicitly mentioned? Is there a potential for memory leaks here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception stores a traceback, which stores all child frames ("function calls") between *raising* and *excepting*. Frames reference all local names and their values, preventing the garbage collection of local names and values.

This means that an exception handler should promptly finish handling exceptions to allow child locals to be cleaned up. Still, a function cannot rely on its locals being collectable immediately after the function ends.

As a result, patterns such as [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) are not reliable to be prompt even on reference counted implementations. When prompt cleanup is required, objects should provide a means for explicit cleanup (for use in `finally` blocks) or preferably automatic cleanup (for use in `with` blocks).

> #### [Objects, values and types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)
>
> […]
> Programs are strongly recommended to explicitly close such objects. The ‘`try`…`finally`’ statement and the ‘`with`’ statement provide convenient ways to do this.

---

One can observe this with a class that marks when it is garbage collected.

```py
class Collectible:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __del__(self, print=print):
        print("Collecting", self.name)

def inner():
    local_name = Collectible("inner local value")
    raise RuntimeError("This is a drill")

def outer():
    local_name = Collectible("outer local value")
    inner()

try:
    outer()
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(f"handling a {type(e).__name__}: {e}")
```

On CPython, the output shows that the handler runs *before* the locals are collected:

```
handling a RuntimeError: This is a drill
Collecting inner local value
Collecting outer local value
```

Note that CPython uses reference counting, which already leads to quick cleanup as soon as possible. Other implementations may further and arbitrarily delay cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, AFAIK, if the exception references some object or another, those won't be collected until the exception itself is collected and, also, if the `except` statement happens to reference some object, that would also postergate its collection until after the block is over. I wonder if there are other, less obvious ways in which catching an exception could affect garbage collection.